# angularjs + download csv file + Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

I am new in angularjs.

I try to download the csv file. So i tried to use angular sanitize and ng-csv files.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <script src="vendor/theme_files/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" class="nav-md">

        <div class="container body" ui-view></div>


        <script src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/lb-services.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/ng-csv/ng-csv.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/offerLetterCtl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/offerLetter.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['lbServices', 'ui.router']).config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url : '/login',
        templateUrl : 'views/login.html',
        controller : 'loginController'
    }).state('addOfferletter', {
        url : '/create_offerletter',
        templateUrl : 'views/create_offer_letter.html',
        controller : 'offerLetterController'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

}]);
```

offerLetterCtl.js (controller folder)

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('offerLetterController', ['$scope', '$location', 'offerLetterService',
    ,function($scope, $location, offerLetterService) { 
        //mycode

}]);
```

offerLetter.js(Service folder)

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('offerLetterService', ['$q', '$timeout', '$http',
function($q, $timeout, $http,OfferLetter) {

        //mycode

}]);
```

create_offer_letter.html

```
<button type="button" ng-csv="getArray()" csv-header="['Field A', 'Field B', 'Field C']" filename="test.csv">
        Export
</button>
```

I followed this link for csv download. [enter link description here](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv)

If i include this lines in controller

```
['ngSanitize', 'ngCsv']


 angular.module('myApp').controller('offerLetterController', ['$scope', '$location', 'offerLetterService',"ngSanitize", "ngCsv"
    ,function($scope, $location, offerLetterService, ngSanitize, ngCsv) {

        $scope.filename = "test";  
}]);
```

Error Details:

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngSanitizeProvider <- ngSanitize <- offerLetterController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/unpr?p0=ngSanitizeProvider%20%3C-%20ngSanitize%20%3C-"<div class="container body ng-scope" ui-view="">"fferLetterController
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the ngSanatize module to your app in app.js I think. Try like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['lbServices', 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize']).config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
```

function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

This is wrong at least:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('offerLetterController', ['$scope', '$location', 'offerLetterService',"ngSanitize", "ngCsv" ,function($scope, $location, offerLetterService) {
```

Your mistake is that you have 5 services in the first part, and you only really inject 3. If you align those it would help:

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('offerLetterController', ['$scope', '$location', 'offerLetterService',"ngSanitize", "ngCsv" ,function($scope, $location, offerLetterService, ngSanitize, ngCsv) {
```

Next to that, this is not right either:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('offerLetterService', ['$q', '$timeout', '$http',
function($q, $timeout, $http,OfferLetter) {
```

You are defining the factory, called offerLetterService, you don't want to insert it in there I think?

Comment: can you please help for this

Comment: please calm down.. Also, edit your code to look a bit more readable in your question, some code is formatted now and some lines aren't

Comment: I added the ngSanatize module in app.js, but same error.

Comment: and no 404's in the console of your browser for not finding certain .js files maybe?

Comment: I am sure on that, the js files are loading

Comment: I think mistake in app.js. code is ===================  angular.module('myApp', ['lbServices', 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize']).config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$ngSanitize',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ngSanitize) {  ==============

Answer (score 0):

Removed the injection from controller. This should work!

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('offerLetterController', ['$scope', '$location', 'offerLetterService'
    ,function($scope, $location, offerLetterService) {

        $scope.filename = "test";  
}]);
```